# Securing a 3rd party Secret in Android

Tags: android, api, security, mobile, jwt

I have a platform for building real-time local apps called [Bashoto](https://bashoto.com) and I am going to build an Android client.

Bashoto applications have the option of being authenticated which is done via generating a one-time use, expiring [JSON Web Token](http://jwt.io) (JWT for short) with the application token and a signature to verify that the token is valid. Each connection will have a unique JWT that is generated by signing the content with a Secret.

In a web environment, this means that the client backend has a copy of the Secret, signs the token and passes it to the client front-end which is then used in a request to the BashotoIO server.

The problem here in the mobile environment, and in this case Android, is that keeping that Secret in the application code itself is a potential attack vector, since someone can inspect the APK to find it.

What is the best way to truly keep the Secret secret in an Android application, while still keeping the Bashoto integration simple and streamlined?

I would like the usage to look something like this

```
Bashoto bashoto = Bashoto.fromAppKey("my-app-key");
bashoto.locate();
BashotoTopic topic = bashoto.topic("my-topic-name"); //token signing and connection happens here
topic.send("Some message that only gets seen by nearby people");
```

Comment: There is a simple rule.  If you really want it to be secret, do not put it on the device.  Whatever you do, your code must be able to find the secret which means that a hacker can find it also.  The only thing you can do is to slow them down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how secure you want the key to be.  You can obfuscate your code using proguard http://responsiveandroid.com/2014/12/10/android-proguard-tutorial.html .  This will still have the string literal in there but will be harder to get through a decompilation but not impossible.

If that's not secure enough then you can't keep it in the APK, you have to keep it on a remote server.  Ideally that server would use SSL to keep the traffic private.  You could fetch the key if you don't have it and store it securely locally using the android keystore https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html .  This means that a user won't be able to decompile your app and find the key.

If you're worried about SSL sucking then you need to move to SSL pinning which will verify the authenticity of any server.  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#Pinning

Comment: This actually matches the web authentication framework I have in place pretty nicely. 

1) Keep only the AppKey on the Android client and be clear that someone can access that key if they tried to.


2) Applications that are using authentication MUST get a JWT from their own server which would be passed to the BashotoIO server.